# PHP Form/MySQL - Cant connect

Tags: php, mysql

My form can be viewed at: www.jbussey.co.uk/bobbin/review.html
My review.php code is as follows:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', '');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

     if (!$db_selected) {
     die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $product = $_POST['product'];
     $comment = $_POST['comment'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO reviewform (name, product, comment, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK) VALUES ('$name', '$product', 
     '$comment')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
     mysql_close();
```

I have taken my DB credentials out for security. The error I get when I run the form is:

Could not connect: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Any reason for this. All help is appreciated

Comment: You should not use the mysql_* functions as they are depreciated see here http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

> Your server is unable to resolve the name example.com to an ip
>   address, i.e. either the dns server is unreachable or there's a
>   misconfiguration in your webserver's dns client. How to resolve this
>   issue depends on your operating system (and configuration).

Comment: I have changed the server, filled the form in and it now outputs a blank screen and no rows have appeared in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is incorrect - you're passing 3 values but you defined 6 columns.

`$sql = "INSERT INTO reviewform (name, product, comment, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK) VALUES ('$name', '$product', '$comment')";`

try this

`$sql = "INSERT INTO reviewform (name, product, comment) VALUES ('$name', '$product', '$comment')";`